# spotify music playlist in website

Tags: javascript, spotify

Does anybody know how to play spotify music on website? I have a play button in my web page, and when I click on it, I want to play background music from my spotify playlist. I don't want to embed spotify playlist on my website with iframe, I want to do that with spotify App (if it is possible), but I don't know how.

Here is the link to my website: http://workshopcafe.com/beta/

Can anybody show me how to create an app and use it, if anybody have done it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spotify URIs. [Here's](http://news.spotify.com/us/2008/01/14/linking-to-spotify/) their help page about it. For playlists, you can link to spotify:user:spotify:playlist:0FQk6BADgIIYd3yTLCThjg, where the last key is the playlist ID, and the second `spotify` is the username of the playlist creator.

Comment: how can it help me on this case? Url will just link to spotify music, isn't it? will that play music in my website?

Comment: @anulik no, if you use the Spotify URI instead of a normal HTTP link, it will play it on the spotify app.

Comment: @anulik Note that I said URI (with an i in the end). It is different from URL (with L in the end) :)

Comment: ok, thanks, but the link you have post http://news.spotify.com/us/2008/01/14/linking-to-spotify/   isn't this just a link to spotify music?  if i use URI, where i have to put it?

Comment: have you done something like this? get spotify music in website?

Comment: @anulik that link was a link to their help page which explains URIs. Read it, and they have some examples of the URIs there. You have to put the URI in your HTML code in an `a` tag.